# Apps deep links and Universal links

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web, hyperlink

(Example)
I have a mobile application and website.
My app has a homepage, Section A, Section B, Section C, and Section D.
Every section is offer a different service. Imagine I am renting every section to a different person.

If a want a single link to open my app, I know this is possible.
But this will open the app itself, and homepage.

What about if I want to open dircetly a single section? such as the link open the app and going to section D direct?

mysite.com/app/sectionD  when this link is shared on whatapp or instagram it is open the section needed directly, not only opening the app homepage.

Can this be done?